# gst-resource-error-quark: Could not write to resource

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, python-gstreamer

I am really new to GStreamer and I am stuck in this error for a long period of time. I am using my mobile as a RTSP camera. I can open the RTSP link in my laptop's VLC properly (In Windows). However, If I try to use this RTSP camera link in GStreamer pipeline I am getting the following error.

```
gst-resource-error-quark: Could not write to resource. (10) 
gstrtspsrc.c(8074): gst_rtspsrc_close (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0:
Could not send message. (Received end-of-file)
```

This is my pipeline. I am trying to save the video as images every few seconds. I am using Gstreamer in WSL Ubuntu latest version (20.1).

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.102:5554
        retry=100
        latency=1000
        buffer-mode=auto
    ! decodebin
    ! videoconvert n-threads=4
    ! videorate
    ! videoscale
    ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=1/10
    ! queue
    ! jpegenc
    ! multifilesink location={SINK_LOCATION}
```

Could anyone help me out here ?

Comment: Not sure for your case, but maybe the decoder selected by decodebin outputs in non system memory and this might explain the quark message. You would use verbose flag of gst-launch (-v) and check what decodebin outputs. For example, if you have NVIDIA hw, if decodebin outputs into memory:NVMM, just use nvvidconv instead of (or before) videoconvert for copying into system memory.

Comment: No. I tried it in another system and it's working. I suspect security issue in my system.